# Is there a way of moving between "integer positions" in a file with C language? (in a file with all ordered integers)

Tags: c, file, search, binary, integer

I need a way to say for example "check the 500.000th integer and confront it with x", i just know that the integers inside the file are ordered from lowest to highest.

I have a file with 1.000.000 integers , i need to find the posizion of the integer X , is there a way to move between integer positions ?
I need to use the binary search without loading the integers in memory.

I've tought about using lseek(), fseek() and so on, but i am not sure how to use them, integers seem to occupy different byte sizes too.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can avoid reading all the file (until the `x` value or `500000` position is reached) sequentially. Maybe [memory mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) helps with speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numerals in the file are different lengths, e.g., “34” is two characters, and “1733” is four characters, there is generally no way to move directly to a specific numeral in the file, because neither you nor the file system knows exactly where in a file a particular numeral begins until you or it examines the file.

Since the numerals are ordered by value, you could find a particular value by guessing where it might be in the file, seeking to that location, reading to find a delimiting character (something that is not part of a numeral, such as a space, comma, new-line, for example), and then reading the numeral that follows. The value of that numeral would tell you whether to move further back or ahead in the file.

To find numerals by index (which numeral it is in the file—first, second, third, and so on), one option would be to read the file, counting numerals, and recording the position within the file of every, say, 100<sup>th</sup> numeral. So you could build an index table that you kept in memory. Then, when you wanted to find some numeral, say the 3437<sup>th</sup>, you could use the table to seek to the 3400<sup>th</sup> numeral and then read characters until you counted 37 numerals.

Another option would be to read the file and rewrite the numerals to a new file using a fixed width for them (adding leading zeros or spaces so every numeral had the same number of characters). Then you could easily seek in the new file since the position of numeral *x* would be *xw*, where *w* is the number of characters used for each numeral, including delimiters.

Note when seeking with calculated offset: In C, you should use streams in binary mode, which supports seeking a specified number of bytes from the beginning of the file. Text mode streams generally do not support this.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!
I will try with numbers with set lenght, your answer has helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A binary search would work even with a *text* file, provided that your integers have clear separators in the file. It would also have the required - though suboptimal - O(lg n) search depth. Just seek to the approximate byte offset and read characters until you find a separator and read the next number following it.

Even more so if you can memory map.

But this is still solving the wrong problem - if you can, you should write the numbers in a fixed-length binary format, and memory map that file and use the standard library `bsearch` function to realize the binary search!

Comment: @EricPostpischil actually we don't know, I just read that OP says they need to do *binary search* and this would then be xy problem. Should have probably closed as unclear instead.